# Creating a script for duplicating a server setup

Tags: 18.04, software-installation

Does Linux have some sort of script which will install the same packages that you have on server A to server B.

Am new to Linux and it was so much work to get it where I wanted to be. But this is my development server.  If I ever have to make a server for public use, it would be nice to make it automatic.

Thanks

Comment: Like this? http://fai-project.org/

Comment: Yes, but that would be from the start.  Was hoping there was something that would read my current install.  Much like MySQL's "dump" feature.

Answer (score 0):

[Trinity Rescue Kit](http://trinityhome.org) has a cloning feature.

Would that be of any use?
It can clone entire harddisk which would include your OS and all files.

[1] http://trinityhome.org/manpages/man8/mclone.8.html

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate on the answer by user64213879:

- If you problem is just a "one shot" then disk duplication is probably the most eeasy solution (remeber to change the network settings of course)
- If your problem is the beginning of a larger replication system (eg, containers or cloud), then you should consider tools like Ansible which allows to to script intsallation and the reproduce them coherently.
  https://www.ansible.com/ is Open Source by Red Hay